# Looking for a short story, romance scifi, about a person who falls love/friendship with a "mayfly" species of human that only lives for 3 days/3 weeks

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

All I remember is on Day/Week 2, the mayfly persona is very blasé about dying the next day/week, and the longer lived one is already kind of mourning/concerned. However the next day/week the mayfly is inconsolable as they realise their mortality.

Anyone got anything?

Comment: I think I’ve read it. Feels like Bradbury maybe.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Bradbury's "Frost and Fire" fits the short lifespan, but there is no longer-lived human falling in love

Comment: Was it maybe called "the petals of a rose"? (Or something like that)

Comment: Something like "The Petals of a Rose" is what I was thinking too. Pretty sure there was a story in Analog with similar title and that theme, sometime late 70s-early 80s. One of the illustrations, if I remember, was a line drawing of an alien shedding rose-petal like appendages.